# Did Pasteur's MD assistant accidently inject himself with rabies?

Tags: history

I recall from my history of science that one of Pasteur's assistants accidentally injected rabies virus into his thigh. I was able to find only two links about this event, one in a book called "Who Goes First?: The Story of Self-experimentation in Medicine" where it states: "Jacques Grancher, the physician who gave the first injections of the vaccine to Meister, accidentally stuck his thigh with a syringe containing live rabies virus. Pasteur then immediately gave him rabies vaccine according to this book. 
[https://www.amazon.com/Who-Goes-First-Self-Experimentation-Medicine/dp/0520212819](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0520212819) page 112

The other reference was also from a book that didn't give the name of the assistant but gave a similar story:
"The needle jabbed into the assistant's leg. Pasteur's vaccine was based on the commonly held theory that resistance to a virus is built up by exposing the body to stronger and stronger  doses of that virus. Therefore, the assistant had just injected a rather strong dose of rabies virus deep into his leg. The terrified assistant immediately asked to receive the full treatment."
[https://www.amazon.com/Scary-Medical-Stories-Marie-Noble/dp/1591942926](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1591942926) "The Fury of Rabies"

I find it odd that other historical sites fail to mention what I consider to be a rather important event. Especially if it resulted in SEVERAL patients being treated at once and not just Joseph Meister. My question is: Can anyone confirm if Jacques Grancher, MD actually did accidentally infect himself with rabies and was saved only by Pasteur's rabies vaccine?

Answer (score 2):

According to this [source](https://books.google.com/books?id=RzOcl-FLw30C&pg=PA450&lpg=PA450&dq=loir%20%20grancher%20rabies&source=bl&ots=bkivmh2rXF&sig=VJ4OqPeR0GM63cc0JoLNVWU9iuA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwilgMme4YPRAhUB3IMKHT0UDw8Q6AEIITAC#v=onepage&q=loir%20%20grancher%20rabies&f=false), yes, it is true, but happened long after the Meister case.

The event was hidden for years and not recorded until after Pasteur's death.